# JSX element type 'X' is not a constructor function for JSX elements

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-dom

After searching for the past 8 hours I cannot find a solution to this. I am getting a message: `JSX element type 'X' is not a constructor function for JSX elements. Type 'X' is missing the following properties from type 'ElementClass': base, linkState`

While working in another file calling a method `renderMessage()` that renders a simple component. My component does render on that parent file but, Typescript keeps throwing this error that not allow me to npm run build. My file has a .tsx extension and my tsconfig has 
`"jsx" : "react"` Any ideas?

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";

export interface MessageProps {
    message: string;
}

export default class RelayMessage extends React.Component <MessageProps> {
    render() {
         return <span>{this.props.message}</span>
    }
}

export function renderMessage(props: MessageProps, target: HTMLElement) {
    ReactDOM.render(<RelayMessage message={props.message} />, target);
}
```

Comment: Not sure, but usually, `React` needs to be imported, but right now, it looks like you're importing the default export as a property of `React`. Just `import React from 'react';` should possibly be enough.

Answer (score 1):

I would ensure you have this line in `tsconfig.json`:

```
"jsx": "react",
```

And make sure your file has a `.tsx` extension, not `.ts`.

Comment: Yep it is. Posting a Fiddle shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Just update your NodeJs version and these errors will be gone